# Using pivot table to find difference between date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 columns that looks like this:

```
    ID  date    account_no  service_name    amount
0   0   2019-09-01  123456789012    AWS CloudTrail  0.00
```

The data is available from 1 Sep to 14 Oct. Can not share due to security reasons :)

I will like to compare 2 dates (21 Sep and 10 Oct) and find the difference.

The following code is working as expected. But I will like to know if there is a better way.

```
x = df[df.date == "2019-09-21"]
x = x[x.columns[3:]]
x.columns = ["service_name", "2019-09-21"]

y = df[df.date == "2019-10-10"]
y = y[y.columns[3:]]
y.columns = ["service_name", "2019-10-10"]

ndf = x.merge(y, on="service_name")

ndf["diff"] = ndf["2019-09-21"] - ndf["2019-10-10"]

    service_name    2019-09-21  2019-10-10  diff
6   EC2 - Other 2.75    2.39    0.36
7   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute  0.16    2.54    -2.38
```

I am trying to find pivot_table like solution where I can get a report of weekly difference, monthly differnce etc.

Comment: Make up some data and show expected output.

Comment: will there be more than one observation of any one `service_name` in a given day?

Comment: @linamnt No. Only one service_name will appear every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) first:

```
ndf = df.pivot(index='service_name',columns='date',values='amount')
#if aggregation is necessary
#ndf = df.pivot_table(index='service_name',columns='date',values='amount', aggfunc='mean')
ndf["diff"] = ndf["2019-09-21"] - ndf["2019-10-10"]
print (ndf)
date                                    2019-09-01  2019-09-21  2019-10-10  \
service_name                                                                 
AWS CloudTrail                                 0.0         NaN         NaN   
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute         NaN        0.16        2.54   
EC2 - Other                                    NaN        2.75        2.39   

date                                    diff  
service_name                                  
AWS CloudTrail                           NaN  
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute -2.38  
EC2 - Other                             0.36
```

Comment: Is it possible to groupby "week" or "month" when the dates are in columns like this and not indexed? In other words how to find service names where I am spending more than the last month?

Comment: @shantanuo - I am thinking about it but no data, so hard to test. Is possible create some mcve?